# How can I improve my database schema for an events management social network (similar to eventbrite)?

Tags: sql, django, database, database-design, social-networking

I have created a basic layout of the database here - https://dbdiagram.io/d/5e3d48489e76504e0ef12a2b.

I'm making it in django, not that I'm sure that's relevant, but it could be.

The concept is an events management site similar to eventbrite but with a larger social feel. Users will have followers etc and when signing up they'll select interests, which will be used to show them events they may be interested in.

The events can be free or not and can be private or not. Users can create and attend events and post photos to the events, which will be displayed in the events page and on both the hosts page (as photos of events hosted) and on the user who posted thems page (apologies about the grammar there).

If anything else isn't about why I've structured it the way I have then please ask.

I'm just wanting to know of any alterations you'd make and why.

Comment: This question is too overly broad to answer. If you have a specific question please ask it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a question and answer forum. This question is designed to start a conversation and cannot be answered.